# PDFJS stopAtErrors does not stop execution when encountering PDF parsing errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, pdf.js

I am using PDFJS to get textual data from PDF files, but occasionally encountering the following error:

> Error: Invalid XRef table: unexpected first object.

I would prefer that my code just skip over problem files and continue on to the next file in the list. According to [PDFJS documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/global.html), setting `stopAtErrors` to `true` for the `DocumentInitParameters` in PDFJS should result in rejection of `getTextContent` when the associated PDF data cannot be successfully parsed.  I am not finding such to be the case: even after setting `stopAtErrors` to `true`, I continue to get the above error and the code seems to be "spinning" on the problem file rather than just moving on to the next in the list. It is possible that I haven't properly set `stopAtErrors` to `true` as I think I have.  A snippet of my code is below to illustrate what I think I've done ([code based on this example](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript)):

```
// set up the variables to pass to getDocument, including the pdf file's url:
var obj = {};
obj.url = http://www.whatever.com/thefile.pdf;  // the specific url linked to desired pdf file goes here
obj.stopAtErrors = true;
// now have PDF JS read in the file:
PDFJS.getDocument(obj).then(function(pdf) {
   var pdfDocument = pdf;
   var pagesPromises = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < pdf.pdfInfo.numPages; i++) {
       (function (pageNumber) {
            pagesPromises.push(getPageText(pageNumber, pdfDocument));
       }) (i+1);
   }
   Promise.all(pagesPromises).then(function(pagesText) {
        // display text of all the pages in the console
       console.log(pagesText);
   });
}, function (reason) {
   console.log('Error!  '+reason);
});
function getPageText(pageNum, PDFDocumentInstance) {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       PDFDocumentInstance.getPage(pageNum).then(function(pdfPage) {
          pdfPage.getTextContent().then(function(textContent) { // should stopAtErrors somehow be passed here to getTextContent instead of to getDocument??
             var textItems = textContent.items;
             var finalString = '';
             for (var i = 0; i < textItems.length; i++) {
                 var item = textItems[i];
                 finalString += item.str + " ";
             }
             resolve(finalString);
          });
       });
    }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Error! '+err);
    });
}
```

One thing I am wondering is if the `stopAtErrors` parameter should somehow instead be passed to `getTextContent`?  I have not found any examples illustrating the use of `stopAtErrors` and the PDFJS documentation does not show a working example, either.  Given that I am still at the stage of needing examples to get PDFJS to function, I am at a loss as to how to make PDFJS stop trying to parse a problem PDF file and just move on to the next one.

Comment: same issue here, any update ?